# Adjust space between acronym and glossary description

Tags: indentation, glossaries

I'm using the glossaries package and I would like to get the acronym descriptions to line up with the nomenclature section above it. Tried using the column styles for the glossary, but none of those allow adjustment of the first column (with the acronyms). See picture for misalignment. Any way around this?

[image: Misalignment]

Comment: Please provide a complete, minimal document showing the relevant settings and including little examples of the acronyms and nomenclature.

Answer (score 8):

This is a solution.

Use a fixed width when issuing `\printnomenclature` (e.g. `2cm`):

```
\printnomenclature[2cm] % <-- change the value here
```

and define a new glossary style `mylong` where you use the same width (`2cm`)

```
\newglossarystyle{mylong}{%
  \setglossarystyle{long}%
  \renewenvironment{theglossary}%
     {\begin{longtable}[l]{@{}p{\dimexpr 2cm-\tabcolsep}p{0.8\hsize}}}% <-- change the value here
     {\end{longtable}}%
 }
```

When you print your glossary use the above style:

```
\printglossary[style=mylong,type=\acronymtype]
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{nomencl}
\usepackage[nonumberlist,acronym]{glossaries}

\newglossarystyle{mylong}{%
  \setglossarystyle{long}%
  \renewenvironment{theglossary}%
     {\begin{longtable}[l]{@{}p{\dimexpr 2cm-\tabcolsep}p{0.8\hsize}}}% <-- change the value here
     {\end{longtable}}%
 }

\makenomenclature

\makeglossaries

\newacronym{BWB}{BWB}{Blended Wing Body}
\newacronym{DOE}{DOE}{Design of Experiments}
\newacronym{FEA}{FEA}{Finite Element Analysis}

\begin{document}
$t_{wb}$ and $w_{fg}$
\newpage

\nomenclature{$t_{wb}$}{Thickness of Stiffener Web (in)}
\nomenclature{$w_{fg}$}{Width of Stiffener Flange (in)}

\printnomenclature[2cm] % <-- change the value here

\glsaddall

\printglossary[style=mylong,type=\acronymtype]

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 6):

It would help to have a minimal working example, but you could just use the `alttree` glossary style and set the width taken up by the name using `\glssetwidest`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[acronym,nopostdot,nonumberlist]{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{twb}{%
  name={\ensuremath{t_{wb}}},
  description={Thickness of Stiffener Web (in)}
}

\newglossaryentry{wfg}{%
  name={\ensuremath{w_{fg}}},
  description={Width of Stiffener Flange (in)}
}

\newacronym{bwb}{BWB}{Blended Wing Body}
\newacronym{doe}{DOE}{Design of Experiments}
\newacronym{fea}{FEA}{Finite Element Analysis}

\setglossarystyle{alttree}
\glssetwidest{BWB}
\renewcommand{\glsnamefont}[1]{\textmd{#1}}

\begin{document}
\glsaddall

\printglossaries
\end{document}
```

This produces:

[image: Image of resulting glossaries]

Comment: How to manually change the spacing e.g. inside the acronym with default glossarystyle?

Comment: you could use `\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.3}\small\normalsize` before the make glossaries command.