# Adjust space between acronym and glossary-mcol description

Tags: indentation, glossaries

To save page space I additionaly use `\usepackage{glossary-mcols}` to get the acronyms printed in two columns. The same space trick from [here (Nicola answers)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/166169/adjust-space-between-acronym-and-glossary-description) unfortunately doesn't work after calling `\setglossarystyle{mcolindex}`. How to get the same distance into the two-column acronyms?
The MWE:

```
\documentclass[oneside]{scrbook}
\usepackage[english,ngerman]{babel} % Multilingual support -> ctan.org/pkg/babel?lang=en

%TOSET Modify list of (glossar, acronyms, symbols) appearance
\usepackage[acronyms,nopostdot,nonumberlist]{glossaries} % Make custom, multiple, sorted lists (abbreviation, glossary(explaining terms), symbols)
\setacronymstyle{long-short}                % behaviour: first time use long term, then use abbreviation
\newglossary*{mysyms}{Symbolverzeichnis}    % custom glossary, type=mysmys
\makenoidxglossaries                        % initialize, the main(def.) glossary gets dedicated to definitions
\newglossaryentry{potato}{name={potato},plural={potatoes}, description={starchy tuber}}  % From the text reference with \gls{<label>}, for headings \glsentrytext{<label>}
\newglossaryentry{cabbage}{name={cabbage},description={vegetable with thick green or purple leaves}}
\newglossaryentry{ROS_def}{name={ROS},description={Operating system connecting various C++ nodes}}

\newacronym{ac:ros}{ROS}{Roboter Operating System}
\newacronym{ac:svm}{SVM}{support vector machine}
\newacronym{ac:II}{II}{Interconnected Intersection}

\newglossaryentry{R}{type=mysyms,name={R},description={rational number amount}} 

\usepackage{glossary-mcols}
\renewcommand*{\glsmcols}{2}

\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
        \glstoctrue
        \glsglossarymark{Glossar}               % change header if wanted
        \setglossarystyle{alttree}
        \glssetwidest{cabbage}
        \printnoidxglossary                 % Shortcut to display all glossaries at once 
        \setglossarysection{section}            % get them on one page
        \setglossarystyle{mcolindex}
        \glssetwidest{ROS}
        \printnoidxglossary[type=acronym]
        \printnoidxglossary[type=mysyms]
        \chapter{title}
    Test use: \acrfull{ac:ros} \acrfull{ac:svm} \gls{R} \gls{cabbage} \gls{potato} \gls{ROS_def} \acrfull{ac:II}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `\glssetwidest` only affects the `alttree` styles. Try changing `mcolindex` to `mcolalttree`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command `\glssetwidest` is only provided for the `alttree` styles (see [Tree-Like Styles](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries/glossaries-user.html#sec:treestyles)). The `glossary-mcols` package provides analogous styles to those in `glossary-tree`, so `\glssetwidest` can also be used with the `mcolalttree` styles, but not with any of the other styles.

The simplest solution is to just replace `mcolindex` with `mcolalttree`:

```
\documentclass[oneside]{scrbook}

\usepackage[acronyms,nopostdot,nonumberlist,toc]{glossaries}

\setacronymstyle{long-short}
\newglossary*{mysyms}{Symbolverzeichnis}

\makenoidxglossaries

\newglossaryentry{potato}{name={potato},plural={potatoes}, description={starchy tuber}}
\newglossaryentry{cabbage}{name={cabbage},description={vegetable with thick green or purple leaves}}
\newglossaryentry{ROS_def}{name={ROS},description={Operating system connecting various C++ nodes}}

\newacronym{ac:ros}{ROS}{Roboter Operating System}
\newacronym{ac:svm}{SVM}{support vector machine}
\newacronym{ac:II}{II}{Interconnected Intersection}

\newglossaryentry{R}{type=mysyms,name={R},description={rational number amount}} 

\usepackage{glossary-mcols}
\renewcommand*{\glsmcols}{2}

\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents

    \glsglossarymark{Glossar}
    \setglossarystyle{alttree}
    \glssetwidest{cabbage}
    \printnoidxglossary
    \setglossarysection{section}
    \setglossarystyle{mcolalttree}
    \glssetwidest{ROS}
    \printnoidxglossary[type=acronym]
    \printnoidxglossary[type=mysyms]

        \chapter{title}
    Test use: \acrfull{ac:ros} \acrfull{ac:svm} \gls{R} \gls{cabbage} \gls{potato} \gls{ROS_def} \acrfull{ac:II}

\end{document}
```